# First page created gives a 404 error message?

Tags: symfony

I have 30 minutes experience with symfony2, I just installed and i'm trying to discover how it works ..

So I followed this example here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

Then, when I execute my url : http://symfony.docker/my_project/web/lucky/number
I obtain this message

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

For your information, when I execute this url:
http://symfony.docker/my_project/web/ 
I got this:

> Welcome to Symfony 2.7.6
>
> Your application is ready to start working on it at:
>   /var/www/html/my_project/

Thanks!

Comment: What about if you go to http://symfony.docker/my_project/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number ?

Comment: It tells me "You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information."

Comment: Comment out line 16 & 17 in web/app_dev.php and it should work, you are getting this message because the vagrant internal ip is not in the list of "allowed" (see line 14). The reason you are getting a 404 is because, without adding app_dev.php, you are accessing the production version of the site which only serves the cached routes. You can clear and rebuild the cache and you will see you route at "http://symfony.docker/my_project/web/lucky/number".. but while developing you should use `.../app_dev.php/...` so that it loads the debug version of your application.

Comment: i don't have any app_dev.php in my web folder, is it normal ?

Comment: You must have, otherwise you wouldn't be able to see the "You are not allowed to access this file" message.

Comment: So i should create an empty app_dev.php file in the web folder ?

Comment: Forget it i just found it.